# Can you please advise me how to simplify these terms?

Tags: calculus

e^(i*π/c) −sgrt(−1) + e^(−i*π/c) -1/i*sin(π/2)− cos(π/c),

e^(i*π/4) + e^(−i*π/2) −(1 + i)/sgrt(2)+ 2sgrt(−1).

Comment: Is $c$ real or complex?

Comment: c is real, I forgot to write it

Comment: Use Euler’s formula and that $\sqrt{-1}=i$.

Comment: This looks very much like a homework exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Expression 1**

$$e^{iπ/c} −\sqrt{-1} + e^{−iπ/c} -\frac{1}{i\cdot\sin(π/2)}− \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{c}\right).$$
We can put the two exponential terms together. By the complex cosine representation we have $e^{iπ/c}+e^{-iπ/c}=2\cos(\pi/c).$ Next, the square root of $-1$ is defined as $i$. Furthermore $\sin(\pi/2)=1$ and $1/i=-i$. Putting all of this together gives us
$$-i+i+2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{c}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{c}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{c}\right).$$

**Expression 2**

With the help of expression $1$ you should be able to also solve the second expression. If you still have questions just ask in the comments.